# var_dump()-ing $_POST variable shows empty array when POSTing a string via jQuery's $.post() method

Tags: php, jquery

Let's put examples to demonstrate my problem:
**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

  <head>

    <title>Testing XHR</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <script>

      $(function()
      {
        const test = "This is a test text.";
        $.post("test.php", {data: test}, function()
        {
          console.log(test);
        });
      });

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

**test.php:**

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

So, when I load `index.html`, it completes `$.post()` request successfully. I have checked it via Chrome's "Inspect" option, under "Network" tab. But when I load `test.php`, it shows empty string. I have tested it to my local server and a live server, results are the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

console log the response you get from `test.php`.

```
$.post("test.php", {data: test}, function(response)
{
    console.log(response);
});
```

loading the `test.php` won't show you the post data.

Comment: Console throws this error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/1498960/test.php' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Comment: are you checking it on remote or local server?

Comment: local server. but i tried it on live server as well, the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

say you sent data at 9 am by running html file. It sends data to php. but as php isn't returning response, you don't get that.
now you ar running php file at say 9.01am. how will you get data now?

You need to print out response.

try the following.

```
$(function()
      {
        const test = "This is a test text.";
        $.post("test.php", {data: test}, function(response)
        {
          console.log({test, response});
        });
      });
```

Comment: Console throws this error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/1498960/test.php' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`